# Mezzanine - custom content type is not showing in admin interface

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I've started a brand new Mezzanine project, added 1 app called "article" to handle a custom content type called "Article".
My folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── article
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── demo1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── local_settings.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── deploy
│   ├── crontab.template
│   ├── gunicorn.conf.py.template
│   ├── local_settings.py.template
│   ├── nginx.conf.template
│   └── supervisor.conf.template
├── dev.db
├── fabfile.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── static
    └── media
```

My `article/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from mezzanine.pages.models import Page

class Article(Page):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=timezone.now)
```

`article/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin
from .models import Article

admin.site.register(Article, PageAdmin)
```

I've already added my app "article" to the project's `settings.py`.
I've used South to migrate the new model class.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

The "Article" content type is not showing in the admin interface!
Why?
I even restarted the server but the content type is still not showing.

The versions I'm using:

```
Mezzanine 4.0.1
   ::                       ::   * Django 1.8.4
  ::    M E Z Z A N I N E    ::  * Python 3.4.3
   ::                       ::   * SQLite 3.8.3.1
   `p.                     .q'   * Darwin 14.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from article.models import Article

class ArticleAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Article
    list_display = ['source']

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: Mezzanine's documentation uses `PageAdmin` - http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#creating-custom-content-types. So may I know why you are telling me to use Django's `ModelAdmin` class?

Comment: From http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html: When registering content type models with PageAdmin or subclasses of it, the admin class won’t be listed in the admin index page, instead being made available as a type of Page when creating new pages from the navigation tree.